# I need to attach a random image generator to an obstacle component in a game

Tags: javascript, html, css

You can check out the source code here: http://site.roaminghound.com/CNIT133finalproject.html 
I need to figure out how to attach the random image generator to myObstacles. Labeling them similarly broke the code. The image generator is currently in the html to show the random image generator works, will be taken out later.

```
function updateGameArea() {
    var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            myGameArea.stop();
            return;
        } 
    }
    myGameArea.clear();
    myBackground.speedX = -1;
    myBackground.newPos();    
    myBackground.update();
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(250)) {
        x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
        minHeight = 50;
        maxHeight = 200;
        height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeightminHeight+1)+minHeight);
        minGap = 150;
        maxGap = 170;
        gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
        myObstacles.push(new component(120, 120, "images/enemy0.gif", x, height + gap, "image"));
        this.img = img;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        myObstacles[i].speedX = -1;
        myObstacles[i].newPos();
        myObstacles[i].update();
    }
    myGamePiece.newPos();    
    myGamePiece.update();
}
/*Below is my array of enemies, it is currently not attached to the enemy 
generator. I have it showing up below the game area with HTML just to prove 
the array works.*/
var changeObstacle = new 
Array("images/enemy0.gif","images/enemy1.gif","images/enemy2.gif",
      "images/enemy3.gif","images/enemy4.gif","images/enemy5.gif",
      "images/enemy6.gif","images/enemy7.gif","images/enemy8.gif",
      "images/enemy9.gif","images/enemy10.gif","images/enemy11.gif",
      "images/enemy12.gif","images/enemy13.gif","images/enemy14.gif",
      "images/enemy15.gif","images/enemy16.gif","images/enemy17.gif",
      "images/enemy18.gif");
function chooseEnemy() {
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * changeObstacle.length);
    document.getElementById("myEnemy").src = changeObstacle[randomNum];
}
```

Comment: is the question you're asking "how do I call the `chooseEnemy` function? Because that function seems to choose a random "changeObstacle" - not sure how that relates to `myObstacle` though

Comment: I tried to use myObstacle to name that function and it broke the code, so currently they are named differently. Thought maybe one could call the other? How do I label the parameter in the third place for myObstacles? It can't stay a single image for the array to work.

Comment: I think it was originally called chooseEnemy, actually.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to spawn various types of enemies in your game. Currently, only the skateboarder type (enemy0.gif) is spawning, but you have prepared 18 other additional sprites (enemy1.gif to enemy18.gif).

**This is a simple solution:**

```
var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (18 + 1));  // Get a random number 0 to 18.
var imgUrl = 'images/enemy' + n + '.gif';      // Form image url.
myObstacles.push(new component(120, 120, imgUrl, x, height + gap, "image"));
```

---

**And here is a method that is based on your attempt.** I changed the method `chooseEnemy()` to return a string which is used by the line that creates the enemy components:

```
myObstacles.push(new component(120, 120, chooseEnemy(), x, height + gap, "image"));

.
.
.

function chooseEnemy() {
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (changeObstacle.length + 1));
    // document.getElementById("myEnemy").src = changeObstacle[randomNum];
    return changeObstacle[randomNum];
}
```

*Note: You need `(changeObstacle.length + 1)`, otherwise the last enemy type would never be spawned!*